# MySql query ignore to show if Sum of rows Quantity condition is true

Tags: mysql

I am stuck on MySql Query execution! I created one table called 'WO'. From this table, there are 3 columns

1. Order QTY (Actual Quantity for the order)
2. Receive Qty (Actual Quantity that has been received)
3. Pending Qty. (Quantity that will be received)

I can add some of my row results. But my target is, if `Order QTY=Receive QTY`, then this row will not be shown during execution. But I failed to capture this part! Need your valuable advice to solve this part.

Below is my code and output in a picture.

```sql
SELECT 
    id,
    ind,
    WONO,
    PRODUCT,
    SUM(QTY) as "Order_QTY",
    SUM(Rec_QTY) as "Received",
    SUM(QTY-Rec_QTY) as "Pending",
    UNIT 
FROM 
    wo 
WHERE 
    Inhouse_Status!="IN-HOUSED" 
Group by 
    ind 
ORDER BY 
    ind DESC
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may filter rows using a where condition eg `WHERE Order QTY <> Receive QTY` or since you are using a `group by` to `sum` total `Order QTY` you may filter the total using a having clause eg `WHERE SUM(QTY) <> SUM(Rec_QTY)`.

Your query could look like:

```sql
SELECT 
    ind,
    WONO,
    PRODUCT,
    SUM(QTY) as "Order_QTY",
    SUM(Rec_QTY) as "Received",
    SUM(QTY-Rec_QTY) as "Pending",
    UNIT 
FROM 
    wo 
WHERE 
    Inhouse_Status!="IN-HOUSED" 
Group by 
    ind, WONO,PRODUCT, UNIT
HAVING
    SUM(QTY) <> SUM(Rec_QTY)
ORDER BY 
    ind DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add condition in you `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT 
    id,
    ind,
    WONO,
    PRODUCT,
    SUM(QTY) as "Order_QTY",
    SUM(Rec_QTY) as "Received",
    SUM(QTY-Rec_QTY) as "Pending",
    UNIT 
FROM 
    wo 
WHERE 
    Inhouse_Status!="IN-HOUSED" AND Order_QTY != Received
Group by 
    ind 
ORDER BY 
    ind DESC
```